# ListView adding first item multiple times

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

So I have a ListView and a custom adapter for it 
I am adding valued to the database and then repopulating the list 
so I added items in the following way : q, w,e,r,t,y,u,i,o,p
the listview populated as follows : q,w,e,r,t,y,q,q,q

This is the custom adapter

```
public class TestListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static ArrayList<FlashCard> flashCardItems;

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Context context; 
    public TestListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FlashCard> results) {
        this.context = context;
        flashCardItems = results;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return flashCardItems.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return flashCardItems.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.flashcard, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.flipper = (ViewFlipper) convertView.findViewById(R.id.flashcard);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.flipper.addView(FlashCard.createQuestionCard(context,flashCardItems.get(position).getQuestion()));


        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ViewFlipper flipper;
    }

}
```

This is the Database Handler

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mySchoolDB";

    // Flashcards table name
    private static final String TABLE_FLASHCARDS = "flashcards";

    // Flashcards Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String QUESTION = "question";
    private static final String ANSWER = "answer";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_FLASHCARDS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_FLASHCARDS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + QUESTION + " TEXT,"
                + ANSWER + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_FLASHCARDS_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_FLASHCARDS);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    // Adding new Flashcard
    public void addFlashcard(FlashCard flashcard) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(QUESTION, flashcard.getQuestion()); // flashcard Name
        values.put(ANSWER, flashcard.getAnswer()); // flashcard Phone

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_FLASHCARDS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    // Getting single FlashCard
    public FlashCard getFlashcard(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_FLASHCARDS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                QUESTION, ANSWER }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        FlashCard flashcard= new FlashCard(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return FlashCard
        return flashcard;
    }

    // Getting All Flashcards
    public ArrayList<FlashCard> getAllFlashcards() {
        ArrayList<FlashCard> FlashcardList = new ArrayList<FlashCard>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_FLASHCARDS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                FlashCard flashcard = new FlashCard(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2));

                // Adding Flashcard to list
                FlashcardList.add(flashcard);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return Flashcard list
        return FlashcardList;
    }

    // Updating single Flashcard
    public int updateFlashcard(FlashCard flashcard) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(QUESTION, flashcard.getQuestion());
        values.put(ANSWER, flashcard.getAnswer());
        db.close();
        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_FLASHCARDS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(flashcard.getID()) });

    }

    // Deleting single Flashcard
    public void deleteFlashcard(FlashCard flashcard) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_FLASHCARDS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(flashcard.getID()) });
        db.close();
    }


    // Getting Flashcards Count
    public int getFlashcardsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_FLASHCARDS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }


    public void deleteAllFlashCards(){
        SQLiteDatabase sdb= this.getWritableDatabase();
        sdb.delete(TABLE_FLASHCARDS, null, null);
        sdb.close();
    }



}
```

and this is the listview

```
public class TestList extends ListView
{
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<FlashCard> stringArray = new ArrayList<FlashCard>();

    public TestList(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        setResults();
    }

    public void setResults() {
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        stringArray = db.getAllFlashcards();

        setAdapter(new TestListAdapter(context, stringArray));
    }

    public TestList(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void addFlashCardDialog() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle("Add flashcard");
        final EditText question = new EditText(context);
        question.setHint("Question");
        final EditText answer = new EditText(context);
        answer.setHint("Answer");
        LinearLayout qa = new LinearLayout(context);
        qa.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        qa.addView(question);
        qa.addView(answer);
        builder.setView(qa);

        builder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                FlashCard f = new FlashCard(question.getText().toString(), answer.getText().toString());
                DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
                db.addFlashcard(f);
                setResults();

            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        builder.show(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`addView()` isn't replacing the view that currently exists.  When the `convertView` comes back to be recycled, 'q' already exists inside the `ViewFlipper`, and you want q to go away and be replaced by 'u'

```
holder.flipper.addView(FlashCard.createQuestionCard(context,flashCardItems.get(position).getQuestion()));
```

Try setting the view inside the view flipper to the new value instead of using addView().

Example:

```
    TextView text = (TextView) ViewFlipper.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    text.setText(flashCardItems.get(position).getQuestion());
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is coming from the `ViewFlipper` you're using in your adapter.

List views in android use view recycling (which is what the convertView is for in getView) but due to how you're handling them every time a view gets recycled you add another view to the flipper, what you need to do is add the view when convertView is null and then modify the view in the flipper to represent your data, not sure how the question card view works so I'm just guessing there.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.flashcard, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.flipper = (ViewFlipper) convertView.findViewById(R.id.flashcard);
        holder.card = FlashCard.createQuestionCard(context,flashCardItems.get(position).getQuestion());
        holder.filpper.addView(holder.card);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.card.setQuestion(flashCardItems.get(position).getQuestion());


    return convertView;
}
```

obviously you'll have to adjust your view holder and add a card field with the proper type and add a setQuestion method to the questionCard view but you get the idea.

Comment: That helped :) but when I click on one item, that item and some random item flips too and I am getting a null point exception at when I click on the last few items in the listview . in my onitemclick I am doing this LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) av.getChildAt(i);
  ViewFlipper vf = (ViewFlipper) ll.getChildAt(0); and  those lines are throwing nullpointer . but thats only for the last few

Comment: I'm guessing `av` is your list view but I dont know, anyway if you want the view you clicked on then use the `view` parameter passed into the onItemClick method.

Comment: I take that back, your solution didnt help :( its doing the same thing